# Rewrite rules in httpd.conf (Apache)

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I am currently migrating to a new server. I want to point the domain from the old server to new server. Some of the old content will live on the old server which will now listen to a new subdomain. This server should forward all traffic back to the subdomain (old server) other than new and updated files, e.g. all traffic coming in under "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" should be redirected to "oldsite.domain.com" excluding a number of directories, e.g. /newsroom

I put together this but I am not sure if it works. Any kind of advice is very much appreciated.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsroom
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://oldsite.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

UPDATE:
This modification works now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search|newsroom).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.domain.com/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:search|newsroom))[^/] http://oldsite.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I am pushing it now - will share the results back.

Comment: Terrific, fingers crossed. :)

Comment: Works almost: I forgot that the root shall also stay and not redirect to oldsite.*. Seems a bit tricky or is it just if REQUEST_URI is empty?

Comment: So I put this together with your help and other feedback I got, see above.